# Force a subordinate CA cert to be signed to include a the CRL distribution point extension?

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, certificate-revocation

How can I attach a `crlDistributionPoints` parameter when signing a CSR I've generated as follows:

```
openssl req -new -key /root/ca/private/private.key -out /root/public.csr
```

I usually sign with:

```
openssl ca -extensions v3_ca -days 730 -out /root/ca/certs/public.cer -in /root/public.csr
```

When I attempt to use `-extfile` to assign a file I've populated with a `crlDistributionPoints` parameter, clearly signing fails.  According to the man page for `openssl ca`, this is because `-extensions` refers to `-extfile` for the configuration profile (in this case `v3_ca`).  Is this correct?

If so, how do I build out a config that contains `crlDistributionPoints` for use with `ca`?

I suppose I don't understand the modular design of the configs well, and am concerned that utilizing `ca` will not work the way I would guess if I write my own `openssl.cfg`?

Comment: The following similar question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966123/howto-create-a-certificate-using-openssl-including-a-crl-distribution-point

Comment: Thanks.  I actually read over that before posting here.  I do not believe that it applies directly to signing a `subordinate CA` certificate, and this was my concern.  Unless it does.

Answer (score 1):

I've reviewed the contents of `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`, and the following should work to produce a usable `-extfile` for use with the previously mentioned command (`openssl ca -extensions v3_ca -extfile /root/ca/opensslx509.conf -days 730 -out /root/ca/certs/public.cer -in /root/public.csr`).

```
echo "[ v3_ca ]" > /root/ca/opensslx509.conf
echo "subjectKeyIdentifier=hash >> /root/ca/opensslx509.conf
echo "authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer >> /root/ca/opensslx509.conf
echo "basicConstraints = CA:true >> /root/ca/opensslx509.conf
echo "crlDistributionPoints=URI:http://CRLSERVER/CRL.pem" >> /root/ca/opensslx509.conf
```

I have *not* tested this at this point.